# react / react-draft-wysiwyg: How to determine truly is blurred?

Tags: reactjs, use-ref, react-draft-wysiwyg

The attached graphic shows my issue. If I click outside of the content, but inside the textarea, which you can see a light grey border around, the `onBlur` event is fired.

I've tried to capture the event and prevent this behaviour using target, but the event looks the same if you click way outside the box - where I want `onBlur` to fire.

So far using a ref has not worked either. I was hoping that would be the solution. Any ideas on how to allow a user to click anywhere within what they are seeing as the component `react-draft-wysiwyg` and NOT fire `onBlur`?

[image: fires blur even when clicking within the visually rendered component]

Answer (score 1):

My fix, though feeling a bit hacky because of needing to handle the first `onClickAway`, was to elevate the `onBlur` call to a `ClickAwayListener` wrapping the `Editor` component like so:

```
<ClickAwayListener onClickAway={() => {
    // Moving onBlur up to support clicking anywhere in component w/o blurring.
    // Handle onClickAway firing once on focus of editor textarea.
    if (firstClick) {
      setFirstClick(false);
    } else {
      onBlur();
    }
  }}
>
  <Editor
    // do not use here: onBlur={onBlur}
    // other props
  />
</ClickAwayListener>
```

Comment: Can you share the code for the `ClickAwayListener`?

Comment: @SangeetAgarwal it is a MUI component. As of today this link will work to show you more: https://mui.com/api/click-away-listener/